# java how to split string from the Value1 + value2 = Value3

Tags: java

I want to split Value1 and value2 from the string Value1 + value2 = Value3(Which is retrieving from excel). I don't required Value3 String. Can some one please answer.

```
Object[] caliculation = readCaliTable.readExcelByColName("Calculations");
    for (int i = 0; i < caliculation.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(caliculation[i]);
        String[] firstValue = caliculation[i].toString().split("\\+");
```

Comment: What is the question then? Am I missing something here? please try to clarify the question.

Comment: You question is confusing. You want to split a string into three different strings? Or do you want to combine two strings into one?

Comment: Do it in two steps: (1) separate left hand side from right hand side by splitting on "=", and (2) separate left hand side into operands by splitting on operators.

Comment: I want only value1 and value2. Value3 has to ignore

Comment: I want yhe strings which is between +

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String[] values = caliculation[i].toString().split("[+=]");
```

This will split the 3 values into an array of 3 elements...

```
values[0] // this is your Value1
values[1] // this is your Value2
```

Comment: If i want two strings shall i write string[0】and string[1]

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
  String[] firstValue ;
  String[] secondValue ;
  Object[] caliculation = readCaliTable.readExcelByColName("Calculations");
  for (int i = 0; i < caliculation.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(caliculation[i]);
      firstValue[i] = caliculation[i].toString().split("\\+")[0];
      secondValue[i] = caliculation[i].toString().split("\\+")[1].split("\\=")[0];
  }
```